# Debuging Mule sub-flow using Java

Tags: java, spring, mule

I am new to Mule. Recently I started to work with Mule. There, I want to write a test class to debug a mule behavior for particular subflow. Mule configuration file contain lots of beans.

Without mocking all the beans, is there a way to isolate the particular sub-flow and test it with real data?

I tried the things mentioned in the https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.6/testing-strategies. But it given spring bean creation error when I execute my test class.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference in testing flow vs sub-flow using Mule MUnit framework. Check this post and you can replace flow with sub-flow: https://unittesters.com/blog/mule-munit-testing-variables-properties/

Answer (score 1):

we can do the testing with Munit in anypoint studio, check with the below doc and it might help you

[Muinit](https://docs.mulesoft.com/munit/v/1.1.1/using-munit-in-anypoint-studio)